# Mapbox Navigation, Rerouting Issue in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, routes, sdk, navigation, mapbox

Navigation keeps on constantly rerouting after every route progress even though the user device location is on the same route. I thought Mapbox automatically handles rerouting only when the user leaves the current route. After I read [this](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/navigation/overview/rerouting/#off-route-detection) part of the documentation, I thought I needed to handle it manually.

Based on documentation, I used below code to handle rerouting manually but the code is deprecated.

```
func navigationViewController(_ navigationViewController: NavigationViewController, shouldRerouteFrom location: CLLocation) -> Bool {
        return navigationViewController.routeController.userIsOnRoute(location)
    }
```

So crash redirects me to this part of Mapbox SDK

```
@available(*, deprecated, renamed: "navigationService", message: "NavigationViewController no longer directly manages a RouteController. See MapboxNavigationService, which contains a protocol-bound reference to the RouteController, for more information.")
/// :nodoc: obsoleted
@objc public final var routeController: RouteController! {
    get {
        fatalError()
    }
    set {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

but `navigationService` not containing `userIsOnRoute` function. Is there an alternative function I could use, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to be a bug. Base on [@luugiathuy](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios/issues/2240) report if you just change SDK to below code if will fix everything, voice and rerouting problem

```
index 47d8132..bc44ed7 100644
--- a/ios/Pods/MapboxCoreNavigation/MapboxCoreNavigation/NavigationService.swift
+++b/ios/Pods/MapboxCoreNavigation/MapboxCoreNavigation/NavigationService.swift
@@ -127,7 +127,7 @@ public protocol NavigationService: CLLocationManagerDelegate, RouterDataSo @objc(MBNavigationService)
public class MapboxNavigationService: NSObject, NavigationService, DefaultInterfaceFlag {

-    typealias DefaultRouter = RouteController
+    typealias DefaultRouter = LegacyRouteController

 /**
  The default time interval before beginning simulation when the `.onPoorGPS` simulation
```

In **MapboxNavigationService** change `RouteController` to `LegacyRouteController` and everything will work as expected.

**The issue is on for almost 4 months, modifying SDK is not good idea but this is and alternative solution until Mapbox fix this issue.**